# Filter out a key from an object for send

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter 1 key out of an object for send. I have a big json tree that has a few sub levels and I just want to filter out the bottom most level before I send it , partly because it's huge and partly because the bottom most level of data is completely un used ( so I would like to cut it out).

So the object has levels like this

```
Account: {name: name, id: id,
                            school: {name: name, id: id, 
                                              classroom: {name: name, id: id } } }
```

So I'm trying to simply cut out the classroom level inside this object -keep in mind there are about a hundred accounts so there are tons).

I previously received a great answer for filtering down to only 1 object (For send) like so

```
 $scope.ids = $scope.myScope.map( function(obj){
    return obj.id;
});
```

I'm wondering, is it maybe possible to use the array.map to say use everything except the classrooms? Or should I be approaching this in  a different way?

Comment: `return { name: name, id: id, school: { name: name, id: id } }`?

Answer (score 0):

One iterative solution will be to go through each and remove the classroom object like this

```
obj = {"Account": {"name": "name", "id": "id",
                            "school": {"name": "name", "id": "id", 
                                     "classroom": {"name": "name", "id": "id" } } }}

for (key in obj){
    try{
        delete obj[key].school.classroom
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("didn't have classroom object")
        }
}
```

This has a linear complexity but is this the best solution.. not sure. Ill learn from this too